# How to use negative lookahead (NOT lookbehind) to match a string that does NOT contain a given substring at a specific position?

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'd like to match certain file types (e.g., ".txt") with a non-empty root name that doesn't end in a particular substring (e.g., "-bad"). With negative lookbehind support, the solution is simple:

```
/.(?<!-bad)\.txt$/
```

Safari, however, *still* does not support negative lookbehinds. Ugh. How could I achieve the same result using a negative lookahead? I'd like to do this with a single regular expression. Please do not provide any non-regex or multi-step solutions.

The test code below shows that I'm close, but one test is still failing.

```js
const regex = /.((?!-bad).{4})\.txt$/;
const tests = [
  ['this-file-bad.txt', false],
  ['this-file.txt', true],
  ['.txt', false],
  ['f.txt', true]
];

const results = tests.map(([input, expected]) => ((regex.test(input) === expected) ? '✅' : '❌') + input);
console.log(results.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*\-bad\.txt$).+\.txt$
```

[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/ehRc2n/1)

The regular expression reads as follows:

- Match the beginning of the string (`^`)
- Use a *negative lookahead* (`(?!...)`) to assert that the string does not end "-bad.txt"
- Match one or more characters followed by ".txt" at the end of the string.

To check for any of several file suffices at the same time (which, based on your comment below, may be helpful) you could write, for example:

```
^(?=.*\.(txt|pdf|csv|docx|html|jpeg)$)(?!.*\-bad\.\1$).+\.\1$
```

The positive lookahead at the beginning has the sole purpose of capturing the file suffix at the end of the string so that a back-reference can be used in the negative lookahead and at the end.

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/s2nK4m/1)

Comment: Thanks to @MikeM for pointing out two careless errors I made.

Comment: Cool. My only concern with this solution is that the extension is provided twice. Since I'm matching far more than just "txt" in my real application, it would mean duplicating a huge list of extensions in the expression. Any way to avoid the duplication of the extension? :)

Comment: If not, I may have to keep @MikeM 's original solution. Wish he hadn't deleted it, heh.

Comment: Demon, if memory serves, @MikeM's regex was `^(?:.{1,3}|.*(?!-bad)....)\.txt$`. You probably think I have a good memory. Members with a certain rep will know otherwise.

Comment: Hehe. I think I'll stick with that one since it's shorter and doesn't rely on back-references (which Safari probably doesn't support either).

Comment: Demon, I edited my question to address your concern. I'd be very surprised if Safari doesn't support back-references, considering that back-references are a pretty basic regex feature and Safari does support negative-lookaheads, a more advanced regex feature. Can a reader familar with Safari's regex support clarify this point?

Comment: I can confirm your expression with back-references does, indeed, work in Safari. :) However, I still prefer MikeM's solution because it's shorter and cleaner.

Comment: That being said, your solution does have the benefit that it doesn't require me to hardcode a "length" of sorts, making it easier to edit the extension list if necessary. In fact, with a mix between 3 and 4-char extensions (as in your 2nd demo), MikeM's solution would probably break. Hmm, decisions, decisions.

Comment: Demon, I hope you will be able to sleep tonight.